# Unable to pull data from an API http://www.infogroup.com/ - Code is showing some errors

Tags: api, excel, vba

I am trying to pull the data for around 1000 companies using this API http://www.infogroup.com/ which uses GET and POST query, GET url has the following format [https://api.infoconnect.com/v1/companies?apikey=4iRztNp5euNzjK3i69xlnpIMa3K6AZCv&companyname=ambarella&resourcetype=enhanced]][1]

I am using VB in excel to pull data. Following is my code which I am using:

```
Function Creditrating(CompName As String) As String
Dim companyname As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim CreditRatingScore   As String
companyname = URLEncode(CompName)
'Assemble the query string
strQuery = "http://api.infoconnect.com/v1/companies?apikey=4iRztNp5euNzjK3i69xlnpIMa3K6AZCv"
strQuery = strQuery & "&companyname=" & companyname
strQuery = strQuery & "&resourcetype=enhanced"

'define XML and HTTP components
Dim googleResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

'create HTTP request to query URL - make sure to have
'that last "False" there for synchronous operation

googleService.Open "GET", strQuery, False
googleService.send
googleResult.LoadXML (googleService.responseText)

Set oNodes = googleResult.getElementsByTagName("CreditRatingScore")

If oNodes.Length = 1 Then
For Each oNode In oNodes
  CreditRatingScore = oNode.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).Text
Next oNode
Else
CreditRatingScore = "NF"
End If

Creditrating = CreditRatingScore

End Function


Public Function URLEncode(StringVal As String, Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean   = False) As String
Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

If StringLen > 0 Then
ReDim result(StringLen) As String
Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
Dim Char As String, Space As String

If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

For i = 1 To StringLen
  Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
  CharCode = Asc(Char)

  Select Case CharCode
  Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
    result(i) = Char
  Case 32
    result(i) = Space
  Case 0 To 15
    result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
  Case Else
    result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
  End Select
Next i
URLEncode = Join(result, "")
End If
End Function
```

The code is working fine for google APIs but is not working for infogroup API.
Please help

Comment: _'is not working'_ is not an adequate problem description

Comment: So when I am using this function as addin in excel it is just creating the URL and displaying it. It is not giving me the value of Credit rating score which I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to use `.LoadXML` for a `JSON` String.

Replace your `Creditrating` function with this function and then try it

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Creditrating("ambarella")
End Sub

Function Creditrating(CompName As String) As String
    Dim companyname As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim rspText As String

    companyname = URLEncode(CompName)

    strQuery = "http://api.infoconnect.com/v1/companies?apikey=4iRztNp5euNzjK3i69xlnpIMa3K6AZCv"
    strQuery = strQuery & "&companyname=" & companyname
    strQuery = strQuery & "&resourcetype=enhanced"

    googleService.Open "GET", strQuery, False
    googleService.send
    rspText = googleService.responseText

    Creditrating = "NA"

    If InStr(1, rspText, """CreditRatingScore"":""") Then
        Creditrating = Split(Split(rspText, """CreditRatingScore"":""")(1), Chr(34))(0)
    End If
End Function
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion. Following is the output I am getting:

Comment: Yes, it is showing the URL when I run the code using the respective function in excel. Is it possible to get CreditRatingScore = A+ as an output in a cell in excel??

Comment: I have updated the code. Please refresh the page. Let me know if it works now?

Comment: Glad to be of help :)